Render native node in JSX/TSX - StencilJS
I am currently facing the following problem:
I have a table component (consisting of CustomBody, CustomHead etc.)
Dummy markup:
<custom-table>
    <custom-table-head>
        ....
    </custom-table-head>
    <custom-table-body>
        <SLOT>
            <custom-table-row>
                <custom-table-cell></custom-table-cell>
                ....
                <custom-table-cell></custom-table-cell>
            <custom-table-row>
        </SLOT>
    </custom-table-body>
</custom-table>

The slot in custom-table-body is filled with custom-table-rows.
The content of the slot is written to a state and should be output in the template without a wrapper div.

    @Element() host: HTMLElement;

    @State() private rows = [];

    private onSlotChange(event: Event) {
        const slot = event.target as HTMLSlotElement;
        const elements = slot.assignedElements();

        for (const foo of elements) {
            this.rows = [...this.rows, foo];
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Host role="rowgroup">
                <slot onSlotchange={(e) => this.onSlotChange(e)} />
                {this.rows.map((item) => item)} <-- Should render content of this.rows as Element 
            </Host>
        );
    }


Unfortunately I only get undefined output, does anyone know how to render native nodes in JSX/TSX correctly?
